# Meaning of 'by' when combined with year

Tags: meaning

> In 1900, 40 percent of the population lived in urban areas; by 1990,
>   75 percent did.

What does 'by 1990' mean in the sentence above? Does it mean 'by the end of 1990'?

Comment: Please let us know where you looked for a possible answer and what you found.

Answer (score 1):

"By," along with a time element, generally means "up to that point," "until," "no later than"; however, in common usage when including a year or a day, it can be taken to mean up to and including that date. For example, "I need to hear from you by Thursday" means no later than Thursday, hence, some time on Thursday is okay. Its usage, therefore, is not always exact.

Comment: In your example, in effect it means 'by the time that statistics for the year 1990 were compiled'.

Comment: @KateBunting How do you get that? If it took two years to compile the statistics for 1990, that doesn't mean that a change of population in 1991 would affect this given statistic.

Comment: @spoko I simply meant that the percentage of people living in cities in a given year will not be known until the statistics have been compiled, so whether the statement refers to the beginning or end of the year is not really relevant.

Comment: @KateBunting I'm not trying to be disagreeable, but how is it not relevant? It is the actual question the OP is asking. If there was a significant population shift in the year 1990, one might reasonably wonder whether that's included in the statistic.  Not to put to fine a point in it, but what's irrelevant is the question of when the statistics were compiled. (Unless they were compiled so quickly as to cast doubt on their veracity, though that's clearly not what you're talking about.)

Comment: @spoko  "By 1990, 75 percent did [live in urban areas]." The writer can only know this by having consulted the published statistics for that year, presumably chosen to make a point because it's a round number. If there was a sudden change that would only show up in the 1991 statistics, we don't know.